# Deciphering the Search Queries Report in GWMT

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

For one of the sites that I am monitoring, the Search Queries report that Google Webmaster Tools provides looks like this -

[image: Graph for two days for Search Queries]

Clearly, both the Impressions and Clicks have increased over the past two days. I am happy, but I am trying to find the reason for the increase, and the same table for this graph has me stumped.

[image: Table for two days for Search Queries compared to previous period]

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closer look at the date range selected tells me that the dates selected show that the past two days have been included.

GWMT does not report the data for the past two days, which means that data for 2 days is being compared to the previous period which has data for 4 days.

This *unfair* comparison has to be avoided.